# Why doesn't the $form crawler change when you do $form->setValues($data);

Tags: symfony, phpunit

```php
        public function testEditSend()
    {
        // making logged in client in parent class.
        $client = $this->makeLoginClient();

        // making fixtures.
        /** @var CustomerRank $customerRank */
        $customerRank = $this->fixtures['customer_rank1'];

        /** @var CustomerChannel $customerChannel */
        $customerChannel = $this->fixtures['customer_channel1'];

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', self::ADMIN_ROUTE.'/customer/channel/rank/'.$customerRank->getId().'/edit/'.$customerChannel->getId());
        $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('register')->form();
        $data = [
            'customer_rank[_token]' => '',
            'customer_rank[name]' => 'rank name No.100',
            'customer_rank[rate]' => '150',
            'customer_rank[code]' => 'testtesttest12345',
            'customer_rank[deliveryFeeFlg]' => '0',
            'customer_rank[customerChannel]' => '1',
            'customer_rank[visible]' => '0',
        ];
        $form->setValues($data);
        $client->submit($form);

        $crawler = $client->request(
            'POST',
            self::ADMIN_ROUTE.'/customer/channel/rank/1/edit/1'
        );

        $updatedForm = $crawler->selectButton('register')->form();
        $this->assertNotEquals($form, $updatedForm);
    }
```

The final assertion in this code is successful. But in the line that says `$form->setValues($data);` the value of $form should have changed. In fact, that line hasn't changed. why? What kind of logic is it?

Comment: instead of comparing the $form/$updatedForm directly, you should probably compare $form->getValues() and $updatedForm->getValues(). since the forms are actually different objects with different field objects and stuff... and even the getValues might be unreliable if the order of fields changes, I can imagine.

Comment: @Jakumi As you pointed out, I changed that to `$this->assertNotEquals($form->getValues(), $updatedForm->getValues());`. The assertion then failed. Both arrays were identical. For the time being, as you pointed out, I plan to change the code to compare the arrays obtained with `getValues()`, but I still feel a bit complicated.